# How do I specify the canvas' ClientIDMode property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using a DevExpress Component (ASPxImageSlider) with a canvas tag inside of one of the slides like this one below:

```js
var video = $("#video")[0];               // video element itself is at index 0 
var vw;
var vh;

var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];             // canvas element itself is at index 0
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");    // getContext on canvas element itself

// setup canvas when metadata is available
video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function () {
    vw = this.videoWidth || this.width;   // these are on video element itself
    vh = this.videoHeight || this.height;
    canvas.width = vw
    canvas.height = vh;
}, false);

// call it straight, use global (or parent) variables
video.addEventListener("play", draw, false);

function draw() {
    if (video.paused || video.ended) {
        return;
    }

    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);  // loop anim. using rAF
}
```

```html
  <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 2px solid blue; width: 100%; height:100%;">
        <video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" class="video" preload="metadata" poster="">
            <source src="images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </canvas>
```

Now, on its own the canvas tag displays the video as expected however once I put it into the slider, it gives me errors like: "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getContext' of undefined or null reference". I reported this to their support team and they state that since canvas is located inside several naming containers it has a complex ID. Their suggested solution was to specify the canvas' ClientIDMode property and obtain the current control via the standard JavaScript getElementById() method. Does anyone have any clue how I would go about doing this (seeing as its not their components that are the problem)? Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: The html5 canvas element has no `ClientIDMode` property. Also, are you sure `ASPxImageSlider` accepts the canvas as an image source (a quick read of the features on their website doesn't indicate so)?

Comment: Well my interactions with their support team did not indicate that their components were incompatible with canvas (I gave them the same code). I have also researched and couldn't find a ClientIDMode for canvas but they seemed to think so. They Even gave me several links. Here is the last quote from them: (Continued below)

Comment: "
Since canvas is located inside several naming containers it has a complex ID (see the "IDs for Controls That Are in Naming Containers" section of the ASP.NET Web Server Control Identification MSDN article). Note that it is a standard behavior for standard controls, so your issue is not connected with our controls. 
As a solution, you can specify the canvas' ClientIDMode property (see the How to: Access Controls from JavaScript by ID MSDN article) and obtain the current control via the standard JavaScript getElementById() method."

Comment: Since `ASPxImageSlider` automatically manipulates its images (eg auto-thumbnailing), and since html5 canvas does not directly expose its content in an image format, I would assume html5 canvas is not compatible with ASPxImageSlider. :-(

Comment: Well in the past I have used an HTML video and an image tag inside the slider (independent of the img-url attribute of the slider). The Template tags are supposed to be able to support html of any kind but I am still awaiting confirmation that canvas is indeed compatible with this as well.

Comment: Update: I was able to fix my problem. Apparently I was accidently misled and their components were actually loading super late (so that when I was calling the canvas it did not actually exist yet (which is what I suspected at first but still was not able to fix it)). Anyway (@markE), thanks for the input.